# помогите разобраться с getline

Tags: c++

есть структура

```
struct Input_Buff{
char * buff;
 int buff_len;
 int input_len;};
```

и есть 
функция , которая должна  считывать в поля структуры строку и запоминать короче сколько там символов

```
void read_input(Input_Buff* buff){
auto bytes_read = std::cin.getline(&(buff->buff),&(buff->buff_len));

if (bytes_read <= 0){
    std::cout << "Error reading \n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

buff->buff_len = bytes_read - 1;
buff->buff[bytes_read - 1] = 0;}
```

и короче я так понял getline **у меня не** возвращает кол-во символом считанных потоком ввода, а компилятор выдает ошибку : **getline was not declared in this scope** , хотя библиотеку string я подрубил

Короче я в полном дерьме, помогите пожалуйста, я вообще не понимаю в чем моя ошибка

Comment: Начнем с того, что чтобы читать - надо иметь, *куда* читать. Вы пытаетесь записывать считанную строку в указатель. Который имеет обычно размер 4/8 байт. Далее, getline, которая член `cin`, объявляется в `iostream`, а не в `string`. Но ваш код не должен компилироваться как минимум из-за полного несоответствия типов - как параметров, так и возвращаемого значений. Нулевой символ тоже описывать не надо... Словом, почитайте [это](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).

Comment: iostream подрублена. Но getline же перегружена, можно в качестве параметров только поток и кол-во указывать без символа завершения. А на счет возвращаемых значений... ТО есть getline возвращает указатель да?

Comment: @Harry , передаваемые параметры в getline у меня верные же. И то есть если getline возвращает указатель, то  в if нужно разыменовывать его чтобы сравнить . ПРосто в русс источниках написано что -1 в случае неудачного считывания

Comment: Они настолько неверные, что надо начинать объяснять с полного нуля, но у меня сейчас просто нет столько времени, чтобы писать большую лекцию... :(

Comment: 1) Член buff просто хранит адрес на память которую Вы ДОЛЖНЫ ВЫДЕЛИТЬ САМИ. 2) getline не возвращает количество прочитаных символов, getline возвращает ссылку на обьект ввода, который Вы используете для её вызова. В Вашем случае - это cin. 3) getline принимает указатель и количество символов (учитывая нулевой символ), а Вы передаете ей АДРЕС указателя и АДРЕС размера.

Comment: а, все, я понял кажись, спасибо, мужики